# UITableView not fully scrolling then crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

(iOS 7) (Xcode 5.0.2) I've got a UITableView, and in the cells are buttons which reload the table with a different array of titles, like a filing system. It has three levels, Users, videos and stats. When I click on a user it loads the array at the index of the row I clicked from the videos array and the same for the stats. It loads up fine, and then I select the user. It shows me the list of videos, but I can't scroll down to see the ones beyond the page. Then, if I click on any video the app crashes. Here are my relating methods :

```
-(IBAction)menu{
    x --;
if(x == 0){
    x ++;
} else if(x == 1){
    [self.titleLabel setTitle:@"Users"];
    [back setEnabled:NO];
} else if(x == 2){
    [self.titleLabel setTitle:@"Videos"];
} else if(x == 3){
    [self.titleLabel setTitle:@"Stats"];
}
[self.table reloadData];
}
-(IBAction)clicked:(UILambdaButton *)sender{
x ++;
if(x == 1){
    [self.titleLabel setTitle:@"Users"];
} else if(x == 2){
    [self.titleLabel setTitle:@"Videos"];
    [back setEnabled:YES];
    y = sender.row;
} else if(x == 3){
    [self.titleLabel setTitle:@"Stats"];
    [back setEnabled:YES];
    z = sender.row;
} else if(x == 4){
    x --;
}
[self.table reloadData];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
NSInteger rows;
if(x == 1){
    rows = [users count];
} else if(x == 2){
    rows = [[videos objectAtIndex:y] count];
} else {
    rows = [[[stats objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:z] count];
}
return rows;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
UILambdaButton *button = [[UILambdaButton alloc]initWithFrame:cell.frame];
if(x == 1){
    [button setTitle:[users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else if(x == 2){
    [button setTitle:[[videos objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else if(x == 3){
    [button setTitle:[[[stats objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:z] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
cell.accessoryView = button;
button.row = indexPath.row;
return cell;
}
```

The UILambdaButton class is identical to UIButton, but it has an property row which is an integer. The menu method is the method attached to my back button to go up a level. When the app crashes it logs the following error:

```
2013-12-07 08:08:23.776 Lambda Does Youtube[4574:60b] -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155fae10
2013-12-07 08:08:23.780 Lambda Does Youtube[4574:60b] *** Terminating app due to  uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155fae10'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2f16ff4b 0x394ff6af 0x2f1738e7 0x2f1721cb 0x2f0c14d8 0x150fab 0x319b7361 0x319b9585 0x319b94dd 0x319b90d9 0x150e1f 0x31917713 0x319176b3 0x31917691 0x3190311f 0x3191f8ad 0x318dabcb 0x31912419 0x31911dbf 0x318e779d 0x318e5fa3 0x2f13b183 0x2f13a653 0x2f138e47 0x2f0a3c27 0x2f0a3a0b 0x33d82283 0x31947049 0x17c5b7 0x39a07ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

EDIT -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
My Users array is an array of strings, my Videos array is an array of arrays, each containing strings and my stats array is an array of arrays of arrays, each containing strings.

Comment: NSLog your videos, users, stats array.

Comment: Check your Stats Array, I think it contains some NSString instead another array like you say. NSLog()

Answer (score 2):

Check your row values

```
[users count]
[[videos objectAtIndex:y] count]
[[[stats objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:z] count]
```

the problem is above one value return `NSString` it not return `NSArry`,`NSString` not have count property

Answer (score 0):

Are the arrays using retain as in: NSArray *array = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil]retain];